# system() not working in for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am having trouble getting `system()` to work inside a for loop in c++. Here is a *example* of my code:

```
string modules[13] = {"requests", "pygame", "pronouncing",
                  "nltk", "pip", "webbrowser",
                  "uszipcode", "geopy", "Nominatim",
                  "bs4", "autocorrect", "spell",
                  "speechrecognition"};
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        system("sudo pip3 install " << modules[i]) // This is what raised the error.
}
```

I get this error:

```
Documents/JoeInstaller.cpp:109:9: error: no matching function for call to 'system'
    system("sudo pip3 install " << modules[i])
    ^~~~~~
```

Comment: system() takes one argument not two.

Comment: Isn't `sudo` going to try to get a password from the user on stdin?  `system()` doesn't provide any way to enter a password into the child process's stdin, so this is unlikely to work.

Comment: Incorrect usage. See again reference of `system()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string modules[13] = {"requests", "pygame", "pronouncing",
              "nltk", "pip", "webbrowser",
              "uszipcode", "geopy", "Nominatim",
              "bs4", "autocorrect", "spell",
              "speechrecognition"};

int main() {
    std::string sudo("pip3 install ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        std::system( (sudo + modules[i]).c_str() ); 
}
```

It is a way of doing it, [System](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) only has one parameter.

Also to avoid asking for a password for each action, run the C++ program with sudo.

Comment: When I do this, it returns `pip3 install --upgrade pip3 install --upgrade pip3 install --upgrade pip3 install --upgrade`. Not any modules. I tried replacing `13` with `i`, but it raised an error. Any ideas?

Comment: If the C++ program is run via sudo, then there's no need to include sudo in the string that is passed to system().

Comment: `Documents/JoeInstaller.cpp:112:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
            system((sudo + modules[i]).c_str());`

Comment: The variable 'i' has not been declared. Check the for loop. `for(int i = ...`